# Distributed computation in Clojure

Tags: clojure, distributed-computing, apache-storm

My new project assignment is to extend existing distributed architecture with a new module for some mathematical calculations with a REST API front-end. The system is written in Java, and ZeroMQ is used for inter-process communication.

I would like to write at least parts of the new module in Clojure. Technically, it will consist of at least 2 submodules, one for calculations per se, another one for sorting and filtering the results of those calculations. Basic requirement is for this system to support distributed computation, so that it can run on as many machines as required for proper performance. Initial advice was to use Apache Storm.

Would Storm work for designing the system with many submodules executing different types of tasks? What other libraries exist in order to make this possible for Clojure-based computation nodes?

If possible, i'd be also very happy to hear your general advice on how to approach this kind of application design with Clojure.

Thanks!

Comment: Just for the part about other libraries: an alternative to Storm is Onyx (https://github.com/onyx-platform/onyx)

Comment: I would recommend to read the Storm documentation. You can access Storm low level Java API (ie, IRichSpoout, IRichBolt, TopologyBuilder) from Clojure to build your program.

Comment: Storm was created by a largly clojure shop (and first (i think) demonstrated publicly at a Clojure meetup). it is well supported. there are clojure spout and bolt APIs

Comment: ZeroMQ also works just fine in Clojure. Maybe take a look at [JeroMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) and [cljzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/cljzmq). I've been using them for about a year. With a couple of caveats, if you already have something ZeroMQ based they work well.

Comment: Thank you for comments! Most probably we will go with Storm, and ZeroMQ for inter-layer communication. This is still being discussed.